# Accessing information inside an .sd file using python

Tags: python, service-definition

I want to know if there is a way to list all folders/files inside a .sd file using Python.  Below is what I am currently working with.

I am writing a script that will access our ArcGIS Online organization, list all service definitions we have for all our users and download them to my PC.  So now I have a folder with 100+ .sd files and now I want to list out all the mxd names inside the sd file.  Using 7-zip I can open these files and see what the name of the MXD that created the service is.

[image: Inside the .sd file]

The only thing I have came close to finding useful is the module libarchive but for whatever reason pip will not install this module.

I currently am using Python 3.6.5 for this particular script but I can switch over to Python 2.7.8 if needed.

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot for @enolan

[image]

On the left is the .sd file and on the right is the file opened up in 7-zip.

Comment: I think those are 7z files. Have a look at [How to read contents of 7z file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797851/how-to-read-contents-of-7z-file-using-python)

Comment: I was on that particular post earlier and that's where they mention using libarchive and I was unable to install this module, appears to be issues currently with it.  I also had no luck with lzma.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can loop through the parent directory to the sd directory (root dir)
2. open the manifest.xml in each extracted sd directory
3. read the line in as xml.
4. Parse the xml and find the element NAME this has the map document title"Name -- thisismapdoc.mxd -- NAME", the element is under parent element Resources "Resources xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfSVCResource'".
5. Write out the name of the mxd to a file or where ever you wanted.

I tried to copy the exact XML elements into this post but they were blocked or ignored by the text editor.

Some quick and dirty code to get you started:
import os, xml.etree.ElementTree

rootdir ='C:\TEST\SD'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'manifest.xml':
            fullfilepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            tree = ET.parse(fullfilepath)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for elem in tree.iter(tag='Name'):
                mxd = elem.text[-3:]
                if mxd == 'mxd':
                    #open your file to write out to

Comment: I was able to find manually go into the manifest.xml document and find the mxd name as you mentioned so this is a good start.  But how are you looping through the the sd directory?

Comment: @HiMyNameIzMatt I added some quick and dirty code above to get you started. I can't format it.

Comment: Are you actually able to loop through the .sd file as it were just a normal folder? I am posting a screenshot of what I have in my original post above..

Comment: No, you'll need to extract the .sds into folders. I thought that you had that step completed. There may be a way to loop thought the .sd files and extract them and then loop through the folders in python. but you'll need to research that.

Comment: Yeah that's my main problem is extracting the .sd file into folders.  I have a case with ESRI open right now and they have a couple guys researching into this for me.  I appreciate your time @enolan.

Comment: @HiMyNameIzMatt You may want to check out this python library. Instead of extracting all the files it looks like you could do a file check in memory and extract the .mxd name https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/

Comment: I tried downloading that module before I made this post @enolan and unfortunately pip will not install it and i get the error - 'Failed building wheel for libarchive'.  I have had no luck in researching the cause of why this error is coming up.